# How to make Flask app that is usable by multiple people at once?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have an app made with Flask, and I have a problem. The app is made to be used as a presentation replacement, to be used with little children. The main page houses a bunch of links. They are made in a way that after the link has been used, it is removed from the page.
Problem is that there is only one page, so the children clicking links will remove them for the teacher. I can set a password myself, but first I need to make it so that each user can open their own version of the page.
Here is the link with [dummy info](https://spacedude101.pythonanywhere.com).
If you find that there aren't links please feel free to comment that the links ran out. I will restart the page and the links will reappear.

Comment: It sounds like you are removing links on the server-side, what about handling the link removal client-side using Javascript? No one person's actions would affect the views of someone else, and the page would be returned to the starting state on refresh.

Comment: I don't really know JS, so i mean i could learn it up. But if the page returns to starting state on reload, then it will reload every time you get off a link, as it goes to another page for this. It works like this: Homepage -- >Question Page --> Homepage